# Superclass Subclass Instantiation

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

Consider the following code snippet:

```
SuperClass superClass = new SubClass(); // Instantiating SuperClass reference
SubClass subClass = new SubClass(); // Instantiating SubClass reference
```

If I list fields/methods of `superClass` object, I can see methods from SuperClass only. Then what's the difference between:

```
SuperClass superClass = new SubClass();
```

and

```
SuperClass superClass = new SuperClass();
```

I know it could be a case of polymorphism and I can use `SubClass` reference, as `SubClass` *IS-A* `SuperClass`, but why would I use `SubClass` reference if I want to instantiate `SuperClass` as I'm getting the same fields/methods by instantiating it with `SuperClass`?

I've seen this question but I'm still confused. [Using superclass to initialise a subclass object java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10177523/using-superclass-to-initialise-a-subclass-object-java)

Edit: I am not talking about interfaces here. I know about interfaces that we can use them to assign objects of the classes that implements them. I'm talking about only superclass.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Edited the question @elliott-frisch. Thanks.

Comment: You're still *programing to the interface* defined by the superclass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create an instance of `SubClass`

```
SuperClass superClass = new SubClass();
```

you can cast `superClass` to `SubClass` and gain access to the methods of `SubClass`. You can't do it when you create an instance of `SuperClass`.

In addition, calling methods of `SuperClass` on an instance of `SubClass` would execute `SubClass` methods when `SubClass` overrides these methods.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. Appreciated.

Comment: Could you please explain in which situation would I require casitng `superClass` object to `SubClass` so that I can access `SubClass'` methods, because if I know that I will require `SubClass` object in advance then I will use `SubClass` object instead of `SuperClass`?